# How to add custom field to events in Splunk?

Tags: events, logging, splunk

I want to add custom fields to specific index and have them log accordingly.

Currently there are only a few default fields such as "host", "index", "sourcetype", etc...

Not sure if this is the best place to add additional data or not.

How can I add more fields?

I am currently using the Splunk SDK to submit events.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing yourself a disservice by testing Splunk with such minimal events.  They don't give you the ability to see what Splunk can do.  You're only getting the default fields because Splunk doesn't know what to do with a single word.  Had you something like "foo=bar" then you'd see Splunk create the 'foo' field.

Every computer has at least one log file you can use for testing Splunk.

It is possible to add fields to events using transforms.  Doing so is an advanced topic and can't be done using the GUI.  I suggest you learn to walk using better sample data before trying to run.

Comment: Are you saying that the fields are not showing up because there is not enough data yet? Once I add more data the additional fields that are being sent in the event will show?

Comment: One word does not a field make, at least not by default.  Your props.conf settings for that sourcetype tell Splunk how to make sense of the data.  The Add Data wizard can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to mention that I was submitting events through the Splunk SDK.

In order to get the fields I wanted to show up in the event, I had to submit the event data as the event name.

```
    var myindexes = service.indexes();
    // Submit an event to the index
    myindexes.fetch(function (err, myindexes) {
    let myindex = myindexes.item("audits-client");


    let evtData = {
        timestamp: Date.now(),
        userAgent: headers['user-agent'],
        protocol: "http",
        file: "null"
    }

    myindex.submitEvent(evtData, {

        sourcetype: "web"

    }, function (err, result, myindex) {
        console.log("Submitted event: ", result);
        return result
    });
});
```